# Why does eyes initially on the horizon line always remain on the horizon line when moving on a ground without elevation?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projection

In [this video](https://youtu.be/qxIcdrE9Vr8?t=77) by Youtuber Love Life Drawing , it's shown objects having their eyes along the horizon line initially still have their eyes on the horizon line when they get closer to the camera. Photos:

> When person is far away  (about 1:40)
> [image]
>
> When person is nearby
>
> [image]

But at the same time, things not on the horizon line have their eye line change as they come closer

> [image]

Why is it that the eyes stay on the horizon line no matter how close or far away the person is?

Comment: If the ground is level enough, all points that are (for example) $1.7$ meters above the ground will lie approximately in a single plane. If the camera is also $1.7$ meters above the ground it will "perceive" all those points along a single line. Then you can color that line yellow and call it the "horizon".

Comment: I think I get it if you could answer with a picture and explain at same time why the dogs height is changing I'll accept the answer